# Drupal 7 - Render fields in node template with different view mode

Tags: drupal-7

I have some fields for node. I hide contents and render fields separately as below

```
hide($content);
print render($content['field_01']);
print render($content['field_02']);
print render($content['field_03']);
print render($content['field_04']);
print render($content['field_05']);
```

I set different field formats in content type at Manage Display" like field_01 is an image and i set large image in Full Content and Thumb image in Teaser view mode. field_02 is a taxonomy reference field which i set Link in Full Content and Plain Text in Teaser view mode.

When i render fields in node template, all fields render as view mode "Full".
Now i want render all fields from default view mode "Full". Only I want to render field_01 & field_02 from Teaser view mode.

Answer (score 0):

Put your code inside an if like this:

```
if($view_mode == 'full'){
    [...]
}
elseif($view_mode == 'teaser'){
    [...]
}
```

Comment: Hello Raniel, with your code its only check $view_mode. but my node template is already in full view mode. so all fields rendered with view mode full. and i just want 2 fields render from teaser view mode.

Comment: Try to use this: `$contentTeaser = field_attach_view('node', $node, 'teaser');`